# Upgrade to 16.04 failed. System says unstable repositories. Getting duplicate packages messages during updates

Tags: upgrade, package-management, updates, 16.04, dpkg

When I attempted to upgrade to 16.04, it told me there were "unstable packages" on my system that I needed to repair. Whenever I run an update, I get the following:

```
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:27 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
```

When I ran `cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list`, I got:

```
1   # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 (20151021)]/ wily main restricted
2   # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted
3   
4   # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
5   # newer versions of the distribution.
6   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
7   deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
8   
9   ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
10  ## distribution.
11  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
12  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
13  
14  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
15  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
16  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
17  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
18  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
19  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
20  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
21  
22  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
23  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
24  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
25  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
26  ## security team.
27  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
28  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
29  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
30  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
31  
32  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
33  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
34  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
35  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
36  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
37  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
38  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
39  
40  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
41  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
42  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
43  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
44  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
45  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
46  
47  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
48  ## 'partner' repository.
49  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
50  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
51  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
52  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
53  
54  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse main restricted universe
55  
56  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
57  # newer versions of the distribution.
58  
59  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
60  ## distribution.
61  
62  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
63  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
64  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
65  
66  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
67  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
68  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
69  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
70  ## security team.
71  
72  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
73  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
74  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
75  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
76  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
77  
78  
79  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
80  ## 'partner' repository.
81  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
82  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
83  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
84  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
85  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main universe restricted multiverse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To easily fix your `sources.list`file you can copy the following block and paste it into your terminal after you switched to be root by `sudo su` (you need to hit <kbd>return</kbd> once after pasting to be back as your normal user):

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.repairbackup
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list << EOF
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
EOF
exit
```

**Note:** This will enable all main repositories the proper way, if you want to make changes on that you can either edit it or use the GUI tool. your old buggy `sources.list` you can find under `/etc/apt/sources.list.repairbackup`.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if my answer was helpful to you and solved your problem you may accept it by clicking on the checkmark beside it.